# Extract method in Android Studio without changing imports

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, intellij-idea

This always happen to me when extracting methods with things using `R`.

For example, I have this:

```
import com.example.R

private fun functionA() {
    holder.price.setTextAppearance(R.style.PriceFont_Grey)
}
```

And when I extract a method I get this (notice that the import changes):

```
import com.example.R.style

private fun functionA() {
    functionB()
}

private fun functionB() {
    holder.price.setTextAppearance(style.PriceFont_Grey)
}
```

I don't want the import to change.

How can I extract methods in Android Studio without changing the imports? I have not been able to find an answer anywhere online.

Comment: it's easy you have done it on first image you shared.
change : private fun functionB() {
    holder.price.setTextAppearance(style.PriceFont_Grey)
}
to this : 
private fun functionB() {
    holder.price.setTextAppearance(R.style.PriceFont_Grey)
}

Comment: @HosseinShahmohammadi I am asking how to prevent the IDE from changing the import when using the "extract function" feature.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing this isn't customizable and is an oversight by the Android team for how this function should behave. Android resource IDs are stored in a weird way where `style` above is a class full of static members, so outside of Android resource IDs you would normally prefer the second way of importing it. So the behavior of the code refactoring feature is following standard Java conventions without treating this like a special case.

Comment: I think you are right, there is no way to customize it. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.